# How to display p4v file history from command line without opening a new p4v instance

Tags: perforce

I am looking to, from command line, display a selected file's history in P4v.
I have seen this documentation page: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2871
Which gives this command:

```
p4v -t history -s //path/to/file.txt
```

It does work. But, it opens a new instance of p4v every single time I run the command.
Would there be a way to do the exact same thing, but instead of creating a new instance of p4v, would use the already existing open p4v application?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `p4vc` -- in theory it sends IPC commands to a running P4V instance rather than launching a new one each time, so it might do what you're looking for.

https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15316